# Android caused by java.lang.outofmemoryerror

Tags: java, android, performance, bitmap

I have this XML and code I added the codes from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html as the guide says  on how load bitmaps Efficiently but I'm still getting out of memory error from logcat. Any help

**UPDATE I'M USING PICASSO NOW BUT STILL GETTING THE OUT OF MEMORY ERROR. THIS IS NUTS**

I have this code ALREADY

```
ImageView targetImage;
ImageView targetImage2;
ImageView targetImage3;
ImageView targetImage4;
ImageView targetImage5;
ImageView targetImage6;
ImageView targetImage7;
ImageView targetImage8;
ImageView targetImage9;
ImageView targetImage10;
ImageView targetImage11;
ImageView targetImage12;
ImageView targetImage13;
ImageView targetImage14;

private Context context;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.app3);
vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.fliping); 
targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
targetImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
targetImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
targetImage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
targetImage5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
targetImage6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
targetImage7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
targetImage8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
targetImage9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
targetImage10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
targetImage11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
targetImage12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
targetImage13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
targetImage14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView14);

Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.gr).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.calvitcdetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage2); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.kapedetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage3); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.glutafitdetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage4); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.pgtdetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage5); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.hilifedetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage6); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.organicbarleyjuicedetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage7); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.barleydetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage8); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.spirulinadetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage9); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.omnisoapdetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage10); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.omnipinkishdetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage11); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.omnidaydetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage12); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.omnitonerdetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage13); 
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.shuyadetails).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(targetImage14);


}
```

Comment: the xml by itself wont prevent to get ride of that error, you must decode bitmap and use it correctly

Comment: Here's my log I included decode bitmap in may activity.java http://pastebin.com/YsQYX70X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any help

Yes, you could  try using [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load your images as it will give you automatic caching of images and memory management, also. I have always found `resize()` method of Picasso helpful.

Also, consider using `RelativeLayout` since you are nesting way too many `LinearLayout`s for displaying a single `ImageView` and this is a performance-killer.

Comment: would you mind giving me some tutorial or documentations I can't find any documentations for picasso. I'm really new with android java coding

Comment: Sorry but How do I use my res/drawable files in picasso? and I got error in Picasso.with(context) can't seem to understand it.

Comment: Instead of a string, just pass your drawable id.

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);

Comment: How big are those images, anyways ?

Comment: Pictures are 800x600 and ranges 150kb -440kb

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing about `OutOfMemoryError`s is that they don't necessarily have anything to do with the line of code where the crash occurred.  If your app has a memory leak, it could be anywhere.  The allocation that used the last bit of memory might be completely unrelated to the leak.  You need to learn how to use a memory analyzer like Eclipse MAT.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its this part of activity that I get this memory leak. The total images I can add is only 5 when I add like another one it began its FC and OutOfMemory Error occurs

Comment: Check the documentation for `Picasso.with(context).load(...)` and see if it retains a reference to the loaded image, or just returns it.  If it's holding onto a reference to the full-sized image, that could be why you're running OOM.  Maybe you need to save a reference to your resized image and then tell Picasso to unload the original.